# Custom Implementation of Repositories Spring-Data-Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to use spring-data-cassandra custom repository implementation. I am using spring-data-cassandra 1.5.M1. The issue is the custom implementation method does not get executed.

Below is the code snippet.

```
public interface JobRepositoryCustom{
   public Job getJobById(String id );
}

@Component
public class JobRepositoryCustomImpl implements JobRepositoryCustom{
    @Autowired
    CassandraOperations template; 

    public Job getJobById(String job ) {


        System.out.println("Some custom implementation");
        return job;
    }
}

public interface JobRepository extends TypedIdCassandraRepository<Job,String>, JobRepositoryCustom {

}
```

The driver program of the same is below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo( JobRepository repository) {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setId("1817086421");
        job.setDescription("My job2 description");
        job.setOneMoreField("Just a new field");
        job.setTitle("Technical  Engineer job");
        repository.save(job);
        //The getJobById is custom method declared in JobRepositoryCustom
        repository.getJobById("My String");
        System.out.println("This after the  job");
        System.out.println("repository = [" + repository+ "]");
        return  null;
    }
}
```

Wether I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename JobRepositoryCustomImpl to JobRepositoryImpl:

Here is a example from my code:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, ProductRepositoryCustom {

}



interface ProductRepositoryCustom {
    public String anyFunction();
}

@Repository
class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepositoryCustom {
    @Override
    public String anyFunction(){
         return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Repository` on `ProductRepositoryCustom` is not required. Besides that, it's the correct answer.